# Как передать коллекцию в качестве параметра?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

При работе двух функций используется одна коллекция:

```sql
function_1 is
begin
    check_dev_t.extend;
    check_dev_t(check_dev_t.last).check_dev:=rec.device_id;
    function 2(par1, передать коллекцию);
end;

function_2(par, принять коллекцию) is
объявить коллекцию
begin
    for 1..коллеция.last
    loop
    ...
    end loop;
end;
```

Как передать коллекцию в качестве параметра? Где можно подробно почитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оракла рядом нет, синтаксис может быть чуть неточным.

Сначала надо определить тип, где-нибудь в пакадже.

```
 TYPE check_dev_t IS TABLE OF T%ROWTYPE INDEX BY INTEGER;
```

а потом определить функцию принимающую этот тип

```
function_2(var1 varchar2, var2 check_dev_t) is
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Коллекции передаются в качестве параметра и возвращаются как результат выполнения функции, точно так же как все остальные типы данных. По умолчанию, как ссылкa на константное значение. Подробнее можно почитать в [Subprogram Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-C0397690-70F4-480D-ADC9-02D277DAA1BB).

Какой тип коллекции выбрать, помогут [обсуждение в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525988/217579).
Простейший и наиболее часто используемый тип -- вложенная таблица строк, полученных из явного курсора. Воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
declare
    cursor data is
        select rownum id, trim (column_value) name
        from xmlTable ('"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"');
    type dataRows is table of data%rowtype;

    function func1 return dataRows is
        res dataRows;
    begin
        open data; fetch data bulk collect into res; close data;
        return res;
    end;

    function func2 (r dataRows) return number is
    begin 
        for i in 1..r.count loop 
            dbms_output.put_line ('func2: '||r(i).id||'/'||r(i).name); end loop;
        return r.count;
    end;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('processed '||func2 (func1 ())||' rows');
end;
/
```

Выведет:

> func2: 1/aaa
>   func2: 2/bbb
>   func2: 3/ccc
>   processed 3 rows