# Какой тип коллекции выбрать

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Прочитав книгу по PL/SQL я так и не понял в полной мере, какой тип коллекции лучше использовать, если не требуется ее использование в SQL командах, не нужно к ней применять операции над множествами и так далее. Потому, что главным преимуществом ассоциативной коллекции  перед вложенной в вышеописанной ситуации, как правило, позиционируется то, что ее не нужно расширить. Но хотелось бы понять, как это влияет на производительность, и какая  коллекция будет более совершенной. Так же хотелось бы понять, какие плюсы дает `varray` по сравнению с вложенной таблицей.

Вопрос можно переформулировать вот так: почему бы в любой ситуации просто не использовать вложенные таблицы, так как они являются самыми функциональными?

Comment: Что такое "просто для работы", вот мне "просто для работы" в 95% случаев вообще хватает обычных возможностей Оракл как реляционной базы, без всяких коллекций и вложенных таблиц. Каждую конкретную задачу надо решать наиболее подходящими именно для нее способами. В разных ситуациях разные подходы дадут лучшую производительность. Если бы были универсальные средства - то не делали бы выбор из многих средств

Comment: В документации есть раздел на эту тему, на текущий момент ссылка такая: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i35815
Если совсем в двух словах, то VARRAY удобны, когда Вам надо, чтобы v(3) всегда означал 3-й элемент массива.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, где и как коллекция используется, универсальной нет.

В PL/SQL коде лучше использовать ассоциативную коллекциию. Немного производительней, не надо расширять, не только числленный индех, но недоступна в SQL и нет конструктора. Также, со слов *Oracle*, они эфективней конвертируются в хост переменные.

В SQL, если надо сохранять как столбец в таблицах, `varrays` и `nested tables` несколько отличаются - `varrays` сохраняются как `LOB`, `nested tables` в собственной таблице (отсюда и название). Некоторые DML доступны для `nested tables`, но недоступны для `varrays`.

Пример ассоциативной коллекции с `varchar2` ключом и инициализацией из таблицы
(используется схема примеров `sh`):

```
declare 
    type items_type is table of varchar2(64) index by varchar2(64);
    items items_type;

    function items_ctor(stmt varchar2) return items_type is
         type pair_row is record (
            key varchar2(64),
            value varchar2(64)
            );
        type refcur_type IS REF CURSOR; --return pair_row;    
        rc refcur_type;
        type pairs_type is table of pair_row index by pls_integer;
        pairs pairs_type;
        ret items_type;
    begin
        open rc for stmt;
        fetch rc bulk collect into pairs;
        for idx in pairs.first..pairs.last loop
            ret(pairs(idx).key) := pairs(idx).value; 
        end loop;
        return ret;
    end;

begin
    items := items_ctor(q'[
        select 'E' || to_char(prod_id) prod_code,  prod_name
        from products
        where prod_name like 'E%'
        ]');

    <<foreach>> declare key varchar2(32) := items.first; 
    begin while key is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line('item(' || key || ')=' || items(key));
        key := items.next(key);
    end loop; end foreach;
end;
/
```

Подробнее в [оф. док. "5 PL/SQL Collections and Records"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A).