# Создание коллекции с типом данных rowtype одной таблицы

Tags: oracle, коллекции, plsql

Каким образом можно создать коллекцию состоящию из `rowtype`, для использования ее в дальнейшем?

С возможностью удаления и добавления ее элементов, причём все элементы типа `rowtype` будут из одной таблицы.  Что-то типа:

```
my_col(1) := table%rowtype
```

С PL/SQL знаком мало и не могу найти подходящий пример.

Comment: "Сразу оговорюсь все элементы типа rowtype, будут из одной таблицы"- а как может быть ещё? Они всегда из одной таблицы, или я вас не правильно  понял?

Comment: "не могу найти подобный пример" - а с какими ключевыми словами вы ищете?  В вашем фрагменте кода не хватает только объявления переменной и примеров даже на этом ресурсе предостаточно.

Comment: Решил проблему, позже скину ответ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллекция определяется, и затем объявляется переменная соответствующая этой коллекции, в декларативной части блока, пакета или функции ключевым словом `type`:

```
create table table1 as select * from dual;
declare 
    type myCollType is table of table1%rowtype index by binary_integer;
    myRow table1%rowtype;
    myColl myCollType;
begin
    select * into myRow
    from table1
    where rownum = 1
    ;
    myColl(1) := myRow;
    dbms_output.put_line ('myColl(1).dummy='||myColl(1).dummy);
end;
/
```

> myColl(1).dummy=X

Различные типы коллеккций инициализируются и заполнятся по разному, подробнее о выборе коллекции в теме [Какой тип коллекции выбрать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525988/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c).

Подробнее про объявление, инициализацую и использование PL/SQL коллекций в [офф. док. Collection Variable Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/collection_variable.htm#LNPLS01307).